# How can I detect changes to Laravel's auth()->user() Object

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How can I detect a change to a specific element in the auth()->user() object?

The general scenario is:

- user is logged-in and the auth()->user() contains a copy of the User model
- A field in the User database table is updated by another (CMS) application
- When the auth()->user() object is next updated, I need to compare the previous value of the field to the current value that was retrieved from the database

I think the easiest solution is to assign the field's value to a session variable BEFORE the auth()->user() is updated, but I cannot figure out where to insert such a session var assignment.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is update the user model with the data modified, you can rehidrate the model instance by using

```
auth()->user()->fresh();
```

additionally you can eager loads any relation in the model.

```
auth()->user()->fresh('comments');
```

In the case you need to compare if any property in the instance have changed making a copy of the original before calling fresh method, you will have to compare properties, unless exists a method which could compare   both instances directly, which I don´t know

Comment: its `auth()->user()` it is a method that returns the user, the property is protected

Comment: Thanks @lagbox , I´l edit the answer as what i meant was the user object.

Comment: My problem is not how to manually update the user model, it it how to have a session variable automatically updated any time the user model is updated automatically (e.g., when Auth::check() is called and Laravel deems it necessary to hit the database to obtain the user model).

Comment: But precisely `auth()->user()->fresh()` will bring the most recent data in your database. The session will be alive while user does not close or expires, I think that the controversial point in your design is what is the source of truth. I wonder is the external app or is the Laravel app? unless, some aspect being controlled by an external service like subscriptions, then subscriptions source of truth is external but email and telephone depends on your app.

Comment: So you will have to determine which is in charge of maintain valid data, because if Telf can be changed by both sides you will never be sure which telephone is the correct one. IDK if I have explained this with clarity, English is not my native language.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like adding an event listener to my User model will do the trick:

```
/**
 * MODEL EVENTS:
 */
public static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    // extra actions when retrieving
    static::retrieved(function($model)  {
        if (Session::get('member_type') != $model->member_type) {
            Session::put('previous_member_type', Session::get('member_type'));
            Session::put('member_type', $model->member_type);
        }
    });
}
```

Each time the User model is retrieved, I update 2 session variables, one containing the current value, the other containing the previous value.